# Audit Plug-in in MYSQL 5.7.5

Tags: mysql, audit

Following error occured while using installing MariaDB Audit Plugin Library (i.e. server_audit-1.1.8.tar.gz) in 5.7.5-m15 MySQL Community Server (GPL) in Centos release 6.5:

ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/server_audit.so' (errno: 13 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/server_audit.so: undefined symbol: _my_thread_var)

Based on the MariaDB documenentation claims that plugin should workin MariaDB or MySQL Server with version 5.5 or newer (MySQL 5.5.14, MariaDB 5.5.20).

I also attempt to use same plugin in MYSQL Server version: 5.6.22 MySQL Community Server (GPL), it works perfectly.

Anyone experienced and resolved above issue?

Comment: MySQL community edition doesn't support Audit trial

Comment: I am using same audit plug-in in 5.6.22 MYSQL Community Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

errno: 13 should be enough of a clue here. 13 is generally permission denied. Check the .so file in your plugindir. It will likely have privs that will prevent the user running MySQL from opening it.

Comment: I am sorry @eroomydna, .so file have enough permission in plugindir in OS. I can see other working plugins(.so) files in the same folder which are having same permission level.

Comment: Have you got SELINUX enbled?

Comment: SELINUX is disabled.

Comment: Ah i should read the error in full. Look at the end of the line. It references a symbol that doesn't exist. This is either a change in the audit api in the mysql server or in the mariadb plugin. This would indicate compatibility issues.

Comment: Yes - It's not working only with MYSQL 5.7.5, which indicates compatibility issue.